# Iphone background processing

Tags: ios, iphone

I am new to Iphone development. We are working on Hybrid Application for one of our customer. We would like to know, whether the following requirement is possible in Iphone, if yes, please let me know your thoughts. I learnt from this forum, all the operations will be suspended once the application is pushed to background.

```
1) Launch the Application.
2) My Applications interacts with the custom backend server for every certain intervals to check for new messages.
3) If yes, then it has to receive the messages and alert the user.
```

It works fine in Foreground mode. But the Customer expects to work on the background mode also, because they need to alert the user immediately within 15 mins once after the message has been dispatched.

Please let me know your thoughts or suggestions.

Thanks,
Ramesh

Answer (score 3):

You can use push notifications to call back the app from the backend when a certain event happens. In iOS7 is possible to send push notification when new content is available. So basically, instead of using a polling mechanism, that is the one you want to implement, it is fairly easy to solve by using a push mechanism.

Comment: Just curious, Facebook, Outlook mails everyone uses push notifications to alert the users if they are running on background?

Comment: I don't know about Outlook but Facebook does. Notifications can also be local, but they need to be scheduled at a specific time by the app itself, therefore cannot be triggered upon receiving a message.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, none of this kind of background processing are supposed to be allowed by Apple (only music etc.)

It's your server which need to send notifications to apple servers which will send it to users (saying "Yeah you have new messages") then your application will display those new message when it wake up.

Comment: I thought iOS7 has background processing?

Comment: Yes there is indeed, after the user is still able to refuse this feature to save his battery life.
By the way, I didn't practice on the background processing, but I'm sure Apple give all what you need.